# missing binded value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/hLsMPWp6O2uL4SheThLR?p=preview

I use push but `{{tab.tabName}}` return blank (line 46) in index.html

Comment: @NitishKumar no it's no, try to type something and click add button

Comment: You keep putting tab.tabName, but it is tab.name. Fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem: (in app.js, under addTab function)

`"name" : capitaliseFirstLetter(this.NewTabName),`

Should be:

`"tabName" : capitaliseFirstLetter(this.NewTabName),`

Answer (score 1):

```
in app.js
```

Replace:

```
$scope.tabs.push({
    "tabId": tabId = tabId + 1,
    "name" : capitaliseFirstLetter(this.NewTabName),
    "active" : true
});
```

To

```
$scope.tabs.push({
    "tabId": tabId += 1,
    "tabName" : capitaliseFirstLetter(this.NewTabName),
    "active" : true
});
```